# RIDE doesnt recognizes keyword 'open browser' even though selenium 2 library is imported

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, robotframework, windows-7-x64, selenium2library

I am very new to Python and Robot Framework and want to learn about it. I decided to install Python and all required packages on my work machine. Since we are behind a proxy, `pip` and `easy_install` don't work. See screen prints below:

[Error when running pip or easy_install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMiln.png)

I then proceeded to install Python and all associated packages manually using source code. I am currently using Windows 7 64 bit Enterprise edition. I downloaded all the source packages and dependencies. I installed them using command `python setup.py install`. Below is the order in which I installed:

1. Python using windows installer. Path was updated.
2. Robotframework
3. Selenium
4. Selenium2Library
5. Decorator
6. wxPython
7. robotframework-RIDE
8. DocUtils
9. Pygments

pip freeze returns the below information:

1. decorator == 4.0.11
2. docutils == 0.13.1
3. pygments == 2.2.0
4. robotframework == 3.0.2rc1
5. robotframework-ride == 1.5.2.1
6. robotframework-selenium2library == 1.8.0
7. selenium == 3.0.2

I also have wxPython (win32 version) installed. I checked the version using below commands. Open command prompt and type commands in the order below:

1. python
2. import wx
3. import wxversion
4. print wxversion.getInstalled()

This gets printed: ['2.8-msw-unicode']

I have checked PATH variable and it is set to include: `C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\`

I have also completed the import of `Selenium2Library` and `selenium` by successfully using `import` command.

I start the RIDE by following below steps:

1. Open Python IDLE from all programs. Below is shown:

   `Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
   Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.`
2. Click on File menu option and then click on Open
3. Go to C:\Python27\Scripts and open ride.py. A python window opens.
4. On new window, click Run and then click Run Module. Alternatively, I press F5 with ride.py window as the current window.
5. Python 2.7.13 Shell window gets updated with below message:

   RESTART: C:\Python27\Scripts\ride.py
6. RIDE GUI opens. I have already created a Test Suite. I add a new test case and type 'open browser' in first cell. The first cell turns yellow i.e. doesnt recognizes `Selenium2Library`.

Please help. I have researched alot and have spent close to 4 working days trying to get this working. I am not sure if I missed installed something or didnt install in the right order. I followed the installation instruction present on link:

https://github.com/robotframework/

Comment: If you are having this much trouble, I recommend using something other than RIDE. While I'm sure it's possible to get it running, I think there are better tools for creating robot test files. There are many tools available that are robot-aware. http://robotframework.org/#tools-editors

Comment: can you please check the spelling given for library, it should be `Selenium2Library`

Comment: Thanks @SaradaAkurathi . I have updated the spelling and the formatting.

Comment: Is it worked after corrected spelling? Please add `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robot` to `path` variable and try to run

Comment: `import` using `Selenium2Library' was successful. I still cant use the `open browser` keyword. RIDE highlights the keyword as yellow. Would it be right to use `import library` command to import the library on the fly

Comment: you should use `Library    Selenium2Library`, try using this

Comment: First, to ease starting RIDE, you could create a Desktop Shortcut with the target `C:\python27\pythonw.exe  -c "from robotide import main; main()"`.

Use the correct format for the import (as Sarada mentioned). It would be useful if you paste here the example test file.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing your current selenium library and re-install this:

`pip install robotframework-selenium2library==1.7.3`